# Function declaration vs expression from a performance point of view?

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-5, javascript-function-declaration

There's many javascript articles on the web comparing function declarations `function foo (){}` to function expressions `var foo = function () {}`. They usually mention things like hoisting, behaviour within conditionals, etc... But I don't recall any of them talking about performance. Is there any difference? Particularily in ECMA5's strict-mode (if that changes anything).

By performance I of course mean execution performance (including lookup, scope traversal, etc..) not declaration performance, although that would be a nice-to-know aswell.

Comment: *"By performance I of course mean execution performance (including lookup, scope traversal, etc..) "* There is none. Both definitions create the same kind of function object.

Comment: The only performance issues I could think of is from using NFE's in certain engines — http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#jscript-memory-management

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function declarations are faster in cases where there's a potential for the function expression to be evaluated multiple times. For example, in code that is called in a loop a hoisted function is only evaluated once, but an expression would be evaluated each time. Besides that, there's no meaningful difference.

Whenever you have a question about a JavaScript performance issue, I recommend checking out JSPerf. Also, Google to see if someone already made one for your question:

Comment: I literally googled for this everywhere both today and yesterday, skimming through many articles on the web. Yet somehow I completely forgot about checking for a jsperf. Also thanks for the short summary in your answer. +1, accepted

Comment: Well, a function declaration in a loop would be a syntax error, so you don't really have that choice.

Comment: @BjornTipling: [Use strict mode](http://jsfiddle.net/54hymcbm/2/), and possibly a browser that doesn't know [quirky function statements](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#function-declarations-in-blocks)

Comment: I was confused by the "Function declaration & expression" in that test, until I realized it's a poor, misunderstood named function expression...

Answer (score 0):

I executed the same tests from JSPerf in Chrome canary 45 and Firefox 37, sadly the results are opposite:

```
function myfunc() {
  alert("yo");
}
myfunc();
```

Chrome: fastest, FF: much slower

```
var myfunc = function() {
    alert("yo");
    }

myfunc();
```

FF: fastest, Crome: much slower

So, the answer is: it depends from the browser/JS engine.